# Would "ordinary" sound self degrading in this context?

Tags: word-usage, meaning-in-context, word-meaning

A: *So you work for that company. Are you some kind of hotshot business man or something?*

B: *Me? No, I'm just an **ordinary** office worker.*

Hi. Does "ordinary" sound self degrading or does it just translate as "normal" here?

Comment: It sounds [unassuming](https://www.lexico.com/definition/unassuming): *Not pretentious or arrogant; modest.*

Comment: It's what the office cocaine supplier might say to the policeman who was interrogating him.

Comment: What role do you fulfil in the office? If you're a low-grade clerk then it would be factual. If you were a senior manager, it would be self-deprecating or even self-degrading.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, it does sound self-degrading.